# Hiding elements from xib builder

Tags: ios, xcode

I am working on a view controller, which has a 4 views that are displayed when their corresponding are pressed. They are hidden until their buttons are pressed. The issue I am having is when I try and add new controls, resize them, move them, etc. I keep dragging them into each other, and can never get the desired result without messing up the others. Is there some way to hide them from view so that I can work on each one at a time instead of having them all on screen?

Comment: Have you instead considered using `child view controllers` instead, and adding/removing these as necessary per interaction by the user with said buttons? (Otherwise, it sounds like your view controller / view hierarchy is going to get messy, fast)

Comment: hmmm, this sounds like the approach I should be taking...thanks!